# python using scipy optimize faild

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, mle

I want to use scipy minimize in order to minimize likelihood function. I need to sum all these function in order to get optimal values to alpha1,alpha2,alpha3,alpha4,beta1,beta 2. my code is:

```
def infected_prob_lh(params):
    alpha1,alpha2,alpha3,alpha4,beta1,beta2=params[0], params[1],params[2], params[3],params[4], params[5]
    return -np.sum([ Nij_339034*np.log(Pj_339034)+ (N_339034-Nij_339034)*np.log(1-Pj_339034),
                  Nij_436000*np.log(Pj_436000)+ (N_436000-Nij_436000)*np.log(1-Pj_436000),
                    Nij_436000*np.log(Pj_436000)+ (N_436000-Nij_436000)*np.log(1-Pj_436000),
                    Nij_817037*np.log(Pj_817037)+ (N_817037-Nij_817037)*np.log(1-Pj_817037),
                    Nij_1282000*np.log(Pj_1282000)+ (N_1282000-Nij_1282000)*np.log(1-Pj_1282000),
                   Nij_4014000*np.log(Pj_4014000)+ (N_4014000-Nij_4014000)*np.log(1-Pj_4014000)])


init_params = [1, 1,1,1,1,1]
minimize(infected_prob_lh,x0=init_params,method='Nelder-Mead')
```

and  I get this:

```
fun: nan
       message: 'Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded.'
          nfev: 1207
           nit: 151
        status: 1
       success: False
             x: array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

I tried to set another initial value and it was unsuccessful. its seem that it worked for only one function in the return statement but I need to find the optimal values for the sum of all those functions.
Be glad for helping.
thanks

Comment: It is not clear what your function is doing. What is the relation between the parameters, and the returned value?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you aren't actually using `alpha1, ...., beta2` in your function anywhere, so when you call `minimize( ... )`, the algorithm changes the values of the parameters, but it doesn't actually change the output value of your likelihood function. As a side note, `nfev` in the output of the minimize function is telling you that it evaluated your likelihood function 1207 times, not just once.

Comment: I using alpha1,...beta 2 inside Pj_i variable.

Comment: @nay : a variable cannot use a parameter

Answer (score 0):

Your return function is invatiant of the input parameters. Thus changing the parameters will not change the output. After the maximum number of iterations the optimizer stops.

Change the return function to be a function of `alpha1,alpha2,alpha3,alpha4,beta1,beta2`

As anser to your comment:

> I using `alpha1,...beta2` inside `Pj_i` variable

We don't have the code of how `Pj_i` is defined (read calculated), but for sure the `Pj_i` is a variable with fixed value and is thus not updated during the iteration of the minimizer.
You need to do some kind of `Pi_j = calculatePi_j(alpha1,...beta2)` to recalculate the values with the current `alpha1,...beta2` before using it to calulate the return value of the fit function.